# Install Windows 8.1 on the new notebook with ssd

Tags: windows, boot, windows-8.1

ASUS X554L 
SSD

**What I try to do:**
So I've bought notebook without system and I want to install windows 8.1 on it.

**What the heck is going on:**
After boot from dvd there is a splash screen with windows logo and after few seconds:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/59Haf.jpg]

**What I've already done**
Disabled boot from anything else than dvd
Set secure boot/unset several times
Enable CRM (as it was default)

I've searched through forums and I cannot find anything similar. Most of the records are about repairing system or installing a new windows with older on the hard drive etc. but nothing close to my problem.

The **only difference** is when I select boot device as  [uefi]...dvd - then I have another fancy message:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwFe.jpg]

**inb4 why Am I installing Windows 8.1** 
Because I need to

I have PC with dual boot so at least I know how to look up for help in this kind of boot-problem, but by now I'm helpless.
Thank you in advance! I've spend few last hours trying to fix that.

Comment: Possibly (?) related: [(system automatically booting from/to recovery partition)](http://superuser.com/q/893343/354511).

Comment: Is the disk GPT or MBR ?? If it is MBR, convert it to GPT with disk management of any system.